# Should we use ! (non-null assertion) or ?. (optional chaining) in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and React, and when I came across this code, I found that either `!` (non-null assertion) and `?.` (optional chaining) can be used.

```js
import { FC, FormEvent, useRef } from "react";

const NewTodo: FC = () => {
  const textInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  function todoSubmitHandler(ev: FormEvent) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //                               v here v
    const enteredText = textInputRef.current!?.value;
    console.log(enteredText);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={todoSubmitHandler}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="todo-text">Todo Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="todo-text" ref={textInputRef} />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">ADD TODO</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default NewTodo;
```

What I know about `!` is that it tells Typescript that this value is never `null` nor `undefined`. On the other hand, `?.` is used to prevent errors when no property found and instead returns `undefined`. In the above example, I can use either `!` or `?.` or even both of them combined `!?.`, and Typescript compiler does not complain. So which one is best and safest to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Optional chaining `?.`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) is *safer* to use than [non-null assertions `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

Consider the following interface:

```
interface Foo {
    bar?: {
        baz: string;
    }
}
```

The `bar` property is optional.  If it doesn't exist it will be `undefined` when you read it.  If it does exist it will have a `baz` property of type `string`.  If you just try to access the `baz` property without making sure that `bar` is defined, you'll get a *compiler error* warning you about a possible *runtime error*:

```
function oops(foo: Foo) {
    console.log(foo.bar.baz.toUpperCase()); // compiler error
    // -------> ~~~~~~~
    // Object is possibly undefined
}
```

---

Optional chaining has actual effects at runtime and *short-circuits* to an `undefined` value if the property you're trying to access does not exist.  If you don't know for sure that a property exists, optional chaining can protect you from some runtime errors.  The TypeScript compiler does not complain with the following code because *it knows* that what you are doing is now safe:

```
function optChain(foo: Foo) {
    console.log(foo.bar?.baz.toUpperCase());
}

optChain({ bar: { baz: "hello" } }); // HELLO
optChain({}); // undefined
```

You should use optional chaining if you are not sure that your property accesses are safe and you want runtime checks to protect you.

---

On the other hand, non-null assertions have no effect whatsoever at runtime.  It's a way for you to tell the compiler that even though it cannot verify that a property exists, you are *asserting* that it is safe to do it.  This also has the effect of stopping the compiler from complaining, but you have now taken over the job of ensuring type safety.  If, at runtime, the value you asserted as defined is actually undefined, then you have lied to the compiler and you might hit a runtime error:

```
function nonNullAssert(foo: Foo) {
    console.log(foo.bar!.baz.toUpperCase());
}

nonNullAssert({ bar: { baz: "hello" } }); // HELLO
nonNullAssert({}); //  TypeError: foo.bar is undefined
```

You should only use non-null assertions if you *are* sure that your property accesses are safe, and you want the convenience of skipping runtime checks.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAPwBcOBx9pcAXjQM5hSgDmA3HcQF8CQ-ARgBXEAjDB0IZJgAOrABQxMNDOgCUtQsQRzW6ADYQAdCfRc1mc2Sj3m5sOgCqixdADCcVhBVtbR5kAHpQ5EMAW0VgMyhkaCh0KH4icOQAWmyczIA+ZAA-YpLCtLCIgHkSACsIaWRgVmRFdFZWYBITAE9kSQATCBhQCH7hAjFJaVl5dEUwbwALOFBbdE1MXTx9IkMQYzNLazWnSicmF3dPHz8AoL58EQI5heXV7EYoGg+yFmQAIkWEBMVn+yAE4OCFWQAAkAKIAGQRlWe8yWKxAKmwAihGQGQxGY1E+AkUhkcmQIDkADlxCCAILtaBgNYbHR6eh7A4WKw2dToU4AQnOlw8Xigvn8gWC42JVJAtIZTKgLJ+5G+jD+gOBoPBkJCGXhSJR+HlipMjP8KqxOINEUAvBuAUp3kAAVbpeOFQZJfZD806NZr44YgUYTfBAA)

Answer (score 4):

Those are completely different things.

The null assertion operator `!.` is you, the programmer, *asserting to the compiler* that you know for a fact that the *property access cannot fail* for reasons the compiler cannot prove. It is no more safe from a runtime error than any other assertion that you the programmer make to the compiler that you know better that it does.

```
const foo = null;
foo!.someProperty; // compiles but you will get a TypeError! Cannot read property 'someProperty' of null or undefined.
```

The other is the optional chaining operator. It is basically shorthand for this common Javascript pattern:

```
const something = foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz;
```

But it's better than just shorthand, because the above will fail if one of those values is falsey but some falsey values support property access. With null coalescing you just write:

```
const something = foo?.bar?.baz;
```

And you're done. And just like the Javascript version it's "safe" in that it's guaranteed not to result in a runtime error from trying to access a property of a null reference.

In the *particular* case you have there, you probably want something like this:

```
const enteredText = textInputRef.current?.value || '';
```

Where it's very clear that the result is a string no matter what.

Comment: Note that `?.` is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and `??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).  `foo ?? foo.bar ?? foo.bar.baz` is similar to `foo?.bar?.baz`